# Align Text in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, alignment, text-alignment

good morning/afternoon or evening to everyone. I have a doubt about how do I suppose to align the text in my app? Here is the image:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWjlo.jpg)

See the problem? I want to bring the second line onwards to where the word "Description" or "Descrição" are. I tried to replace the Row widget for Column but didn't work, nothing appeared on my screen.
Also my code below:

Padding(

```
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 20),
child: Row(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
   children: <Widget>[
     Text(
       "Descrição :",
       style: TextStyle(
         fontSize: 16,
         height: 1.5,
         color: Colors.green.shade400),
       ),
     SizedBox(
       width: 5,
     ),
     Flexible(
       child: Text(
          widget.description,
          textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 16,
            height: 1.5,
            color: Colors.green.shade600),
          ),
     ),
     SizedBox(
       height: 10,
     ),
   ],
 ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Row`, you should use `RichText`

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: 'Describe :',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, height: 1.5, color: Colors.green.shade400),
      ),
      TextSpan(
        text: widget.description,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, height: 1.5, color: Colors.green.shade600),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```